# Junit Mocking of 2 methods

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, spy

This the definition of my class:

```
class A
{
    public b method1()
    {
        //some code
    }
}

class Z
{
    A a = new A();
    public c method2()
    {
        z = a.method1();
        //some code validating z
    }
}
```

I want to test method2 using junit.
The method1() call in method2() should return a valid z.
How should I go ahead?

Comment: Did you mean you want to mock method**1**??? You shouldn't be mocking the method you want to test...

Comment: If you want to test some method with mockito its better  that make you a new class and make the correct anotattions, remember to import the JAR necessary. Here is an example. However, ive never seen a mocked method like. @mock public void {};

Comment: http://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/mockito-example/

Comment: Please note the changes in the question

Answer (score 0):

What should `b`, `c` and `z` be in your sample-code?

Usually you mock every other object your method under test is invoking or those invoked objects require, f.e. `a.method1()` call can be mocked like this:

```
// Arrange or given
Z sut = new Z();
Object method1RetValue = new Object();
A mockedA = mock(A.class); 
Mockito.when(mockedA.method1()).thenReturn(method1RetValue);

// set the mocked version of A as a member of Z
// use one of the following instructions therefore:
sut.a = mockedA;
sut.setA(mockedA);
Whitebox.setInternalState(sut, "a", mockedA);    

// Act or when
Object ret = sut.method2();
// Assert or then
assertThat(ret, is(equalTo(...)));
```

As `a` is a member of your test-class, you will need to set the mocked version first though, either via direct field assignment, setter-methods or via [`Whitebox.setInternalState(...)`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/internal/util/reflection/Whitebox.html#setInternalState%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) as depicted in the sample code above.

Note that the mocked method currently returns an object, you can return what ever the method returns. But as your example lacks a real type I just used an object here.

Comment: Thanks Roman! But, assume that "z" is a complex data type and cannot be used as "method1RetValue". It HAS to be computed using an actual call. I have seen Mocktio.when(mockedA.method1()).thenRealMethodCall() sort of functions but it doesnt work. Can you please help me?

Comment: If you want to invoke a real method call simply use `spy(new A())` instead of  `mock(A.class)` f.e. If `method2()` however should return a fully instantiated obect of type `Z` you should consider returning a fake-object, which you fill with data you need for the test, instead of the real object. Remember that unit-tests simply checks the logic within the method you are testing - nothing more, nothing less. If you want to test that the real objects play together as expected, consider implementing an integration or even end-to-end test